# What Azure service to use to send daily POST request to Webhook endpoint at specific hour

Tags: javascript, azure

I need to know what Azure service can I use (I have an Azure account with a lot of credit so I prefer to use it) to send a POST request to a Slack Webhook.

The message is a JSON object which should have randomized content. If done with JS, for example, this would be the code:

```
const gifsArr = [...] //array with gifs
const textsArr = [...] //array with texts
const titlesArr = [...] //array with titles

const getRandomFromArr = arr => {
    return arr[Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length)];
}

const sendPost = () => {
    const endpoint = 'https://hooks.slack.com/...';
    const message = {
        text: getRandomFromArr(textsArr),
        attachments: [
            title: getRandomFromArr(titlesArr),
            image_url: getRandomFromArr(gifsArr)
        ]
    }

    fetch(endpoint, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(message),
        headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    });
}
```

And I need to send it everyday at, say, 10:15 am (this is the part I don't know how to do).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Sajeetharan said, I ended up using Azure functions.

I used VS Code Azure Tools extensions to create and selected "Timer" when creating the project as the trigger.

This generates the file `function.json`, with this code:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myTimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 15 10 * * *"
    }
  ]
}
```

That way the code inside the `index.js` file will run everyday at 10.15. Also, since it's Node, I had to use `https` node package instead of fetch (which is part of the browser API).

So, instead of the fetch part, this is what it goes:

```
var host = 'hooks.slack.com';
var path = '/services/..../...';

var options = {
  hostname: host,
  path: path,
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }
};

var req = https.request(options);
req.write(JSON.stringify(message));
req.end();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either use [Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/scheduler/migrate-from-scheduler-to-logic-apps) or [`Azure Timer Functions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer)

From Docs about Azure Logic Apps:

> Azure Logic Apps is a cloud service that helps you schedule, automate,
>   and orchestrate tasks, business processes, and workflows when you need
>   to integrate apps, data, systems, and services across enterprises or
>   organizations.

From Docs about Azure Functions:

> A timer trigger lets you run a function on a schedule.

Comment: I didn't downvote, I'll check out Azure Functions and user a timer like the link you gave.

Comment: I did not downvote but I would assume it is due to the fact this is a link only answer and could be a comment because of that.

Comment: hope it makes more sense now